# Java Docs says interfaces cannot have fields.Why?

Tags: java, interface

I was reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/multipleinheritance.html) and it clearly states that `One significant difference between classes and interfaces is that classes can have fields whereas interfaces cannot.`How could this be possible because Java Docs also says `all fields in interface are public,static and final`.

Comment: A `public static final` field is considered a constant.

Comment: A `public static final` is not considered as a field, but as a `static` member. 

The docs rather refer *field* as something non-static.

Comment: @all but what about `public String x="abc"` because it doesn't show any compilation error when i declare it in an interface

Comment: The compiler will make it `public static final String x = "abc"` for you.

Comment: @Fresher It is implicitly `static`.

Comment: @all So as far as i understood firstly I can't declare any field in java without intializing it.Secondly if I declare any field in java say `public String x="abc"`.Then by default it becomes public,static and final.Am i right?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Am i right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How could this be possible because Java Docs also says all fields in interface are `public`, `static` and `final`.

From [Java Language Specification. Chapter 9. Interfaces. 9.3. Field (Constant) Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3) (emphasis mine):

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is **implicitly** `public`, `static`, and `final`. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.
>
> <sub>If two or more (distinct) field modifiers appear in a field declaration, it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production for `ConstantModifier`.</sub>

This means that every field in the interface will be considered as a `public` constant field. If you add `public`, `static` and `final` or some of these modifiers or none of them, the compiler will add them for you. That's the meaning of **implicitly**.

So, having this:

```
interface Foo {
    String bar = "Hello World";
}
```

Is similar to have

```
interface Foo {
    public String bar = "Hello World";
}
```

That is similar to

```
interface Foo {
    static bar = "Hello World";
}
```

The three interfaces will compile to the same bytecode.

Also, make sure that your fields declaration in an interface follow the subnote. This means, you cannot narrow the visibility of a field in an interface. This is illegal:

```
interface Foo {
    //compiler error!
    private String bar = "Hello World";
}
```

Because `bar` won't be `public` and it defies the standar definition for fields in an interface.

Comment: ok now I understood it completely.Thanks for such a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

A `static final` field is a constant value and is present in the class itself, not in an instance of the class. The instance of the interface cannot have any fields, even though the Interface itself may, and even on the Interface itself you are limited to defining constants.

Comment: But what if I declare `public String x="abc` in java.

Comment: You are wrong i have written `public String x="abc` in my interface and still it is not giving me any error.You yourself try it.

Comment: `public String x = "abc"` that's a legal syntax. It's just that the compiler adds the `static` implicitly when you don't add it yourself. And of course the reason is that because you can never instantiate an interface and it doesn't make sense to have an instance field in it.

Comment: @BHeshGurung and final also.

Comment: @BheshGurung Good point, I've always just put static and final since I think it is clearer that way but you are right. They are assumed if you don't put them in manually.

Answer (score 2):

When an `object` is created using `new` all the `fields` will be initialised either to its value or its default value.
Since you cannot instantiate an `interface` you cannot have any `fields`.
But you can have `constants` in your `interface` and thats why all `fields` by default are `public static final`

See [jls](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html)

Comment: But what if I declare `public String x="abc` in java.

Comment: @Fresher you will get compiler error, since the its not `final`

Comment: @SajanChandran *you will get compiler error, since the its not final* false. The compiler will mark it as `static final` for you, similar to add a default constructor for a class if you don't declare any constructor.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza the compiler wont mark `static final` if you already have any `modifier`, it will add only if we declare like `String x="abc"`.

Comment: @SajanChandran check the JLS link you have posted in your answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Oops yes !!.. i realised.